# Let $G=\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ and $H=\left<(2,2)\right>$. Determine the order of the factor group $G/H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ and $H=\left<(2,2)\right>$.
Determine the order of the factor group $G/H$.

I know that $\Bbb Z$ has infinite order. So the external direct product of $\Bbb Z$ is another group with infinite order. It follows that G has infinite order.

What about $H$, I can say that it is a subgroup of $G$. 
$H=\left<(2,2)\right> = \{ (x,y) | x,y \in 2\Bbb Z \}$
So H has infinite order. $G/H$ is infinite over infinite!

Is anything wrong in my explanation?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, 
$|G/H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ if and only if $G$ and $H$ are finite. Here
$$G/H=\mathbb Z2\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: I know that $|G/H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ if and only if $G$ and $H$ are finite, but $G$ has infinite order. So how can determine the order of the factor group? Can i say something about the order of the factor group $G/H$?